# SOM (Kohonen) using the term document matrix

Tags: r, clustering, self-organizing-maps

Language: **R**

Package: **kohonen**

Function: **som**

I have a term document matrix (tdm) with 64 terms (row) and 1017 documents (columns). I want to use the self-organized-map to cluster the terms on 25 cells. In order to do that I have done:

```
somres <- som(as.matrix(tdm), grid=somgrid(ydim=5, xdim=5, 'hexagonal'))
```

- My target: I want to map every single term on the 25 cells to see how it varies on them.
- What I need: I'm looking for an object with 5x5 = 25 rows and 64 columns (or viceversa) in which I have 25 codebooks, and a vector with 64 values for each codebook (one for each term). I need it to map a single term on the 25 cells.

I cannot find it on the object somres (I have seen all the attributes on it). Do you have some ides before I change the package?

EDIT: the problem was simply in the fact that I used the "term document matrix" as input. If you use the "**document term matrix**" (package: koRpus) it works well. What I was looking for, in that case, is in `somres$codes`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `kohonen`'s `plot` function? You can use the `type="mapping"` to show where objects (rows) are mapped, for example. Also, if you do `str (somres)`, you'll see its contents, which includes `unit.classif`.

EDIT: Whoops, missed the fact that you've looked into `somres` already. You'll have to make the array you want from what you've got. Since `plot` can do it, it's possible. You might also want to look at `map` in `kohonen`.

Comment: Thank you Wayne. In this case the solution was another one: in somres$codes there was the solution, but it was wrong. That happened because I used in input the term-document-matrix (tdm). All works well if I use the document-term-matrix instead.

Comment: Yes, `kohonen` will be row-oriented, so you had to transpose the matrix.